# Permutations, compositions and associativity properties

Tags: permutations, inverse, function-and-relation-composition, associativity

Let n be a positive integer, and let σ : {1, . . . , n} → {1, . . . , n} be a one-to-one and onto map.
Then σ is called a **permutation** on n elements. The set of all permutations on n elements
is denoted by S<sub>n</sub>. The set S<sub>n</sub> is important in understanding the determinant. Suppose τ is
a permutation on n elements. If there exist i, j ∈ {1, . . . , n} with i $\ne$ j such that τ (i) = j,
τ (j) = i and τ (k) = k for all k ∈ {1, . . . , n} \ {i, j}, we say that τ is a **transposition**.

(a) Let σ, τ ∈ S<sub>n</sub>. Define στ := σ ◦ τ . That is, στ is τ composed with σ. Prove that
στ ∈ S<sub>n</sub>.

(b) Let σ<sub>1</sub>, σ<sub>2</sub>, σ<sub>3</sub> ∈ S<sub>n</sub>. Prove that (σ<sub>1</sub>σ<sub>2</sub>)σ<sub>3</sub> = σ<sub>1</sub>(σ<sub>2</sub>σ<sub>3</sub>).

(c) Let *I* : {1, . . . , n} → {1, . . . , n} denote the identity permutation. That is, *I*(*i*) := *i*
for all *i* ∈ {1, . . . , n}. Show that, for all σ ∈ S<sub>n</sub>, Iσ = σI = σ.

(d) Given σ ∈ S<sub>n</sub>, show that there exists a unique element σ
<sup>−1</sup> ∈ S<sub>n</sub> such that σσ<sup>−1</sup> =
σ<sup>−1</sup>σ = I.

### My Answers:

(a)

στ(i) = σ(τ(i)) = σ(j) = m for some m $\in$ {1, . . . , n}

στ(j) = σ(τ(j)) = σ(i) = g for some g $\in$ {1, . . . , n} \ {m}

στ(k) = σ(τ(k)) = σ(k) = b for some b $\in$ {1, . . . , n} \ {m. g} $\forall$ k$\in${1, . . .,n} \ {i, j}

since σ is one-to-one and onto, therefore στ is a permutation of n elements so στ$\in$S<sub>n</sub>

(b)

since σ<sub>1</sub>, σ<sub>2</sub>, σ<sub>3</sub> ∈ S<sub>n</sub>, σ<sub>1</sub>, σ<sub>2</sub>, σ<sub>3</sub>: {1, . . . , n} $\to$ {1, . . . , n}. For any k $\in${1, . . . , n}, then

((σ<sub>1</sub>σ<sub>2</sub>)σ<sub>3</sub>)(k) = (σ<sub>1</sub>σ<sub>2</sub>)(σ<sub>3</sub>(k)) = σ<sub>1</sub>(σ<sub>2</sub>(σ<sub>3</sub>(k)))

and

(σ<sub>1</sub>(σ<sub>2</sub>σ<sub>3</sub>))(k) = σ<sub>1</sub>((σ<sub>2</sub>σ<sub>3</sub>)(k)) = σ<sub>1</sub>(σ<sub>2</sub>(σ<sub>3</sub>(k)))

since ((σ<sub>1</sub>σ<sub>2</sub>)σ<sub>3</sub>)(k) = (σ<sub>1</sub>(σ<sub>2</sub>σ<sub>3</sub>))(k) $\forall$ k $\in${1, . . . , n}, we have (σ<sub>1</sub>σ<sub>2</sub>)σ<sub>3</sub> = σ<sub>1</sub>(σ<sub>2</sub>σ<sub>3</sub>).

(c) σ : {1, . . . , n} → {1, . . . , n}, let σ(*k*)=m for some k, m $\in$ {1, . . . , n}, then

Iσ(k) = I(σ(k)) = I(m) = m and σI(k) = σ(I(k)) = σ(k) = m $\forall$ k$\in${1, . . . , n}

(d)

Since σ is one-to-one and onto, it is an invertible mapping, thus σ<sup>-1</sup> exists and is unique by the properties of the inverse. suppose σ(*i*)=*j*, then σ<sup>-1</sup>(*j*)=(*i*), thus

σσ<sup>-1</sup>(j)=σ(σ<sup>-1</sup>(j))=σ(*i*)=*j* thus σσ<sup>-1</sup>=*I*

σ<sup>-1</sup>σ(*i*) = σ<sup>-1</sup>(σ(*i*)) = σ<sup>-1</sup>(*j*) = *i* thus σ<sup>-1</sup>σ = *I*

> How correct/incorrect am I? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These all seem fine to me except for part a; I don't quite understand your argument for that one. You are trying to show that $\sigma\tau$ is a one-to-one and onto map from $\{1,\ldots,n\}\to\{1,\ldots, n\}$.

To show the map is one-to-one, you might suppose that $\sigma(\tau(i))=\sigma(\tau(j))$. Then since $\sigma$ is one-to-one, you have $\tau(i)=\tau(j)$, and similarly, since $\tau$ is one-to-one, it must be that $i=j$. Therefore $\sigma\tau$ is one-to-one.

To show the map is onto, let $k\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$. Then since $\sigma$ is onto, there is some $j$ such that $\sigma(j)=k$. Similarly, since $\tau$ is onto, there is some $i$ such that $\tau(i)=j$. Then $\sigma(\tau(i))=\sigma(j)=k$, so $\sigma\tau$ is onto.